# How to have a row have different auto incrementation for each new foreign key

Tags: sql

I need two tables one being Account and the second being Transaction. The account would have a unique id and would be a foreign key inside the Transaction table. Each account would need it's own transaction id's starting from 1.

So account with id of 1 would have transactions with id's starting from 1 and then The next account with an id would have it's own set of transactions with id's starting from 1.

Comment: I've removed [[tag:java]] as I have no idea what the above is about Java. I've also removed [[tag:sql-server]] and [[tag:mysql]] because they are conflicting. Your question is also lacking a question. Take the time to [edit] your question to significantly improve it.

Comment: Why do you need transaction ids to be account-specific?